# How to grab the text while using selenium

Tags: html, selenium, selector

I'd like to know how I can grab the adress of this site with selenium:

[page](https://www.bisnode.de/upik-profile/316095801/apple_gmbh/)

I tried to store it within

```
address = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('main-content-cell.p-bottom').text

print(address)
```

But if I print the address nothing gets printed in the console. I think its because there are multiple elements with the classes "main-content-cell.p-bottom". What kind of locator strategy do I need to use?

I also tried

```
address = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('main-content-cell.p-bottom').get_attribute('innerText')
print(address)
```

and

```
address = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('main-content-cell.p-bottom').get_attribute('')
print(address)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is valid css:

```
address = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.main-content-cell.p-bottom:nth-child(2)').text
```

or

```
address = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.main-content-cell.p-bottom:last-child').text
```

Comment: Thanks! How do I find out which nth child it is in future? Can I see it directly in google inspector or do I have to search for my class and see how many hits I get and see which number mine is?

Comment: @Lehas in dev tools you can see you have found two elements by selector `.main-content-cell.p-bottom` so if you need actually to get first one use `:nth-child(1)`, if second one use `:nth-child(2)`

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking check mark if that answer helped you

Comment: did it! how would I go about extracting the company name?
i tried: company = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.company--name').text but it doesn't work.

Comment: I can't see issue with selector '.company--name', should be fine

Answer (score 0):

You can use here `(//div[@class='main-content-cell p-bottom'])[last()]` or `(//div[@class='main-content-cell p-bottom'])[2]` `xpaths`
So `address = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//div[@class='main-content-cell p-bottom'])[last()]').text`  should work